# What's the least expensive way to get the number of rows (data) in a SQLite DB?

Tags: sql, sqlite

When I need to get the number of row(data) inside a SQLite database, I run the following pseudo code.

```
cmd = "SELECT Count(*) FROM benchmark"
res = runcommand(cmd)
read res to get result.
```

But, I'm not sure if it's the best way to go. What would be the optimum way to get the number of data in a SQLite DB? I use python for accessing SQLite.

Comment: What client language are you using?

Comment: @Mark : For now, it's python, but it can be C++ and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct but I would add an alias to make it easier to refer to the result:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM benchmark
```

Regarding this line:

> count size of res

You don't want to count the number of rows in the result set - there will always be only one row. Just read the result out from the column `cnt` of the first row.

Comment: You are correct, I got something wrong, I changed it. Thanks.